# get value from bootstrap dropdown menu in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using twitter bootstrap and just new in concept of spring mvc. I am using unordered list to make dropdown. I want to select some value from drop down list and want to use it in controller. Other part are ok and i am able to use them in controller but how to get the value from list i don't know.
 my html part is something like this

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/Web/password.html">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
            </span> 
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" name="userName" type="email" required="" autofocus="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Applications</i></span>
            <div class="btn-group" id='btnn'>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span data-bind="label">Select One Application</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="height:200px;overflow: auto;" >
                    <c:forEach var ="entry" items="${listOfApp }">
                        <li value="${entry }">${entry }</li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and my controller is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/password.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public String submit(@RequestParam (value ="userName") String userName,
            @RequestParam (value ="entry") String entry) {  

        System.out.println(entry+" "+userName);

        return "Hi";

    }
```

I am trying to get the value through @requestParam but it is showing error on the server.  can someone help me. I tried very long but did not get any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can someone help me in this problem. From long time i am trying to solve but i am not getting any solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think request parameters get values from URI, so you can post

```
/password.html?entry=uhuu&userName=petergriffin33
```

If you want to do form submissions which has parameter values in request body, maybe there is model needed, you can read on from 
[Spring form submission tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

Comment: i am getting the username. but my problem is how to get entry value. here i am printing the values through forEach loop. so how to get corresponding entry value.

Comment: What does it do if you make parameter "entry" optional? @RequestParam (value ="entry", required = false) Also could be that it's actually a list not string?